# NFC Tag Facebook Authentication

Tags: android, facebook, nfc

I have an app which requires facebook authentication to login. Is it possible to achieve the same with the NFC Tag. If yes, how can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It´s not possible without user interaction, you can only use the NFC to open an authorization URL on a phone, for example.